# mongodb - most efficient way of calculating missing indices in sequence

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Given a collection with lets say 1.000.000 entries and each of them have their own unique property called number which is indexed. How can I efficiently find the lowest gap in the number sequence.

An easy example would be a sequence of indexes like: 1,2,3,4,6,7,10, where I would like to get back the number 5 since this will be the lowest missing number in the sequence.

Is there a possible way (maybe aggregation) without the need to query all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be with a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/). With a cursor, you can manually iterate through the documents until you find one that matches your criteria.

```js
var cursor = db.coll.find({}).sort({number: 1});
var prev = null
while (cusor.hasNext()) {
  var curr = cursor.getNext()
  if (prev && prev.number + 1 !== curr.number) break;
  prev = curr;
}
```

Comment: Sadly the cursor just Just seems to iterate Up to 20 Times ( Docs pointing this out ). Also I have a bad feeling about this, since the cursor function is Not executed via mongodb ( its executed on my node application), which means that I have to iterate/fetch a lot of data ( many iterations ) on each check and this could consume a lot of time

Comment: You could use a $projection to limit the amount of data you're looking at & run this in the shell.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know the min, max, and number of documents, you should be able to write an app-side binary search to quickly find that document

Comment: I dont know the max beforehand ... Could you explain What you mean by App Side binary search ? Do I Not need all of the indeces on memory For that ?

Comment: I have to look into $projection tomorrow, maybe there will be a possibility, but projections also sound like I have to fetch all of the data at the end

Comment: r.e. $projections -- not necessarily! If the $projection is able to be returned using a covered index, it will only pull that data into the wired tiger cache. at the very end, you'd want to fetch the final document that you found

Answer (score 0):

One is get all the numbers and find the ones missing between them.

An aggregate example that you can use to not have to get them all. https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-to-find-missing-sequence/123771/2

```
// Assuming the sample data with sequence numbers from 1 thru 10 as follows:

{ id: 1 },
{ id: 2 },
{ id: 4 },
{ id: 7 },
{ id: 9 },
{ id: 10 } 

// And, note the missing numbers are 3, 5, 6 and 8. You can use the following aggregation to find them:

db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          nos: { $push: "$id" } 
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          missing: { $setDifference: [ { $range: [ 1, 11 ] }, "$nos" ] } 
      } 
  }
])
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.